# Analysis of duplicate rows in a DataFrame under specific conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

Be the following DataFrame:

| ID | code | date | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GER | 0000 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| USA | 1234 | 2021-04-03 | IN |
| USA | 7283 | 2021-03-11 | OUT |
| GER | 7384 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| FRA | 6523 | 2021-04-12 | IN |
| ITL | 1111 | 2021-04-05 | IN |
| USA | 1234 | 2021-04-03 | IN |
| GER | 2222 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| ITL | 0392 | 2021-04-05 | IN |

First I want to get the duplicates by date, ID and direction, but that its code column value is different.

```
 df = df[df.duplicated(['date', 'ID', 'direction'], keep=False)]
```

The following table is obtained:

| ID | code | date | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1234 | 2021-04-03 | IN |
| USA | 1234 | 2021-04-03 | IN |
| GER | 7384 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| GER | 0000 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| GER | 2222 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| ITL | 0392 | 2021-04-05 | IN |
| ITL | 1111 | 2021-04-05 | IN |

Finally I want to delete the rows that are repeated also in the code field. That is, I want to obtain the following table:

| ID | code | date | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GER | 0000 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| GER | 7384 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| GER | 2222 | 2021-02-05 | OUT |
| ITL | 0392 | 2021-04-05 | IN |
| ITL | 1111 | 2021-04-05 | IN |

I hope you can help me to do it in a few simple lines of code.

Finally for each date, I want to show how many lines of code there are:

```
2021-02-05: 3 matches
2021-04-05: 2 matches
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
   out = df[df.duplicated(['date', 'ID', 'direction'], 
                         keep=False)].drop_duplicates(
                             subset=["code"], keep=False).pivot_table(
                                 columns=['date'], aggfunc='size')
```

output:

```
date
2021-02-05    3
2021-04-05    2
```